# Как разместить ссылку NSURL в Core Data?

Tags: objective-c, ios, coredata

Как разместить ссылку NSURL в `Core Data`?

проблема в том что ссылка длинная и содержит разные символы, которые  x-code считает за операторы, из-за этого он ее обрезает

```
https://gmt.telekom-dienste.de/query?callback=jQuery16203304807513486594_1405512207013&gmt_request=%7B%22boundary%22%3A%7B%22n%22%3A5
```

поэтому разместить ее как NSString не получается

Comment: @daves, зачем вам CoreData сейчас, если вы не можете урл в стринг преобразовать?? Поучите матчасть, для начала.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String, не??))

А потом:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL urlWithString:yourString]
```

Comment: добавил уточнение

Comment: @daves, да ладно))

    NSString *yourString = @"https://gmt.telekom-dienste.de/query?callback=jQuery16203304807513486594_1405512207013&gmt_request=%7B%22boundary%22%3A%7B%22n%22%3A5";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:yourString];

Comment: и куда мне теперь этот NSURL  поместить? @property у меня идет NSString
+  ошибка такая Invalid compression specifier B
Таким успехом зачем мне еще NSString создавать?, я ее уж сразу в NSURL поместил бы

Comment: @daves, как так то?????? Я же в основном ответе написал, в чем сохранять, а NSURL *url - это просто для наглядности, как получить урл из стринга.

Comment: в общем ошибка было в другом)